Select times in one table that are more than a certain amount of time away from times in a different table using MySQL
I bet that the answer is already written, and that I haven't found it with any keywords I've searched. If so, please just point me there and I'll delete the question. It's 1:30 in the morning and I've been at this a while, so plesae forgive if I get my merds wixed up.
Question: In MySQL, how can I query the times in one table that are outside a given interval of all the times in another table?
In the example tables below, if I wanted to select everything in tableA that was two hours or more away from a time in tableB, is that possible?
Clarification: For my purpose, daylight savings transitions, timezones, and date wrapping over midnight can be ignored/disregarded.
Sample tables:
tableA
times
00:00:00
00:30:00
01:00:00
01:30:00
02:00:00
02:30:00
03:00:00
03:30:00
04:00:00
04:30:00
.... all the other times in the day on 30 minute increments
22:00:00
22:30:00
23:00:00
23:30:00

tableB
11:00:00
15:30:00

Desired result:
00:00:00
to
09:00:00
13:00:00
13:30:00
17:30:00
to
23:30:00

updated, working query:
set @dayToCheck = '2024-04-01';
set @earliest = '09:00:00';
set @latest = '17:00:00';
set @breakStart = '00:00:00';
set @breakDuration = 0;
set @inc = 59;


select t.times from times t 

#the time isn't taken
where t.times not in (select a.time from aptSchedule a where a.date = @dayToCheck)

#the time is within the regular schedule
and t.times >= @earliest
and t.times <= @latest

#the time is not during a break
and t.times not in (select s.times from times s where s.times >= @breakStart and times < DATE_ADD(concat(@dayToCheck," ", @breakStart), INTERVAL @breakDuration HOUR))

#the time is outside of the allotted appointment increment
and not exists 
    (select 1 from 
        (select time from aptSchedule b where date = @dayToCheck) dr
    where abs(time_to_sec(timediff(t.times,dr.time))) <= @inc*60);


Do times wrap?  So that 23:30 in table b would exclude 00:30 in table a?

Are you ignoring daylight saving transitions (would require a timezone and specific date?)

Those are great questions, and for this particular project, it's actually safe to ignore both time zones and date wrapping, but there's a good chance that I'm way off base about how to best approach this.

@ysth I'd actually be glad to see the syntax to match tables or results based on whether they fall in to any numerical range of another table. I've always done this through running multiple queries, where I select values from one table and then run a series of queries against another to get the values within or without of range of the other table. I just don't think I've been doing that right.

select times from tableA where not exist (select 1 from tableB where abs(time_to_sec(timediff(tableA.times,tableB.times))) < 120)

Thank you. I think that's in the right direction. Playing with that I learned the following: The 120 should actually be however many seconds we're separating the results on, like 7200 for two hours. It also multiplies the reiteration of tableA by however many times were in tableB, like if they're two times taken in tableB, it'll go through the list of times twice in the output. That can be fixed by using DISTINCT. Lastly, it's really slow, like 2.5 seconds for my particular case. It's probably better to filter outside of MySQL.

Yes, this isn't going to be fast.  But it does not multiply, did you change it to an anti join or something?

I'm not sure why it multiplied last night, but I was a little delirious by 2-3 am. I updated the actual code sample, and aside from being slow, it works. If you made your comment an answer I would accept and +1.

Crudely, just look for times in table B less than 2 hours different:
select times
from tableA
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tableB
    where abs(time_to_sec(timediff(tableA.times,tableB.times))) < 7200
)

If you have a lot of rows in table B (which didn't sound to be the case), you may benefit from having an index on tableB.times and using that:
select times
from tableA
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tableB
    where tableB.times > subtime(tableA.times,'02:00:00') and
        tableB.times < addtime(tableA.times,'02:00:00')
)

All of this assumes tableB doesn't have any times before 2am or after 10pm, or you don't need to exclude tableA rows that are on the previous or following day.  It also assumes daylight saving doesn't exist, and e.g. 1am is always 2 hours before 3am.
